# sensor data is not uploading on artik cloud

Tags: json, node.js, websocket, cloud

I am trying to send sensor data to artik cloud via node.js. (using web socket and serial port). But its sending null. Anyone knows the reason? I just copied the code from tutorial so there is no syntax error.

```
var webSocketUrl = "wss://api.artik.cloud/v1.1/websocket?ack=true";
var device_id = "####";
var device_token = "#####";

var isWebSocketReady = false;
var ws = null;
var serialport = require("serialport");


var portName = 'COM5';
var sp= new serialport.SerialPort(portName, {
    baudRate: 9600,
    parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\r\n")

});
var WebSocket = require('ws');

/**
 * Gets the current time in millis
 */
function getTimeMillis(){
    return parseInt(Date.now().toString());
}

/**
 * Create a /websocket bi-directional connection 
 */
function start() {
    //Create the websocket connection
        isWebSocketReady = false;
    ws = new WebSocket(webSocketUrl);
    ws.on('open', function() {
                console.log("Websocket connection is open ....");
        register();
    });
    ws.on('message', function(data, flags) {
                console.log("Received message: " + data + '\n');
    });
    ws.on('close', function() {
                console.log("Websocket connection is closed ....");
    });
}

/**
 * Sends a register message to the websocket and starts the message flooder
 */
function register(){
        console.log("Registering device on the websocket connection");
    try{
        var registerMessage = '{"type":"register", "sdid":"'+device_id+'", "Authorization":"bearer '+device_token+'", "cid":"'+getTimeMillis()+'"}';
                console.log('Sending register message ' + registerMessage + '\n');
        ws.send(registerMessage, {mask: true});
                isWebSocketReady = true;
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error('Failed to register messages. Error in registering message: ' + e.toString());
    }   
}

/**
 * Send one message to ARTIK Cloud
 */
function sendData(temperature){
    try{
     //   ts = ', "ts": '+getTimeMillis();
            var data = {
                "temp": temperature

               };
        var payload = '{"sdid":"'+device_id+'", "data": '+JSON.stringify(data)+', "cid":"'+getTimeMillis()+'"}';
        console.log('Sending payload ' + payload);
        ws.send(payload, {mask: true});
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error in sending a message: ' + e.toString());
    }   
}

/**
 * All start here
 */


start(); // create websocket connection

sp.on("open", function () {
    sp.on('data', function(data) {
            if (!isWebSocketReady){
                console.log("WebSocket is not ready. Skip sending data to ARTIK Cloud (data:" + data +")");
                return;
            }
            console.log("Serial port received data:" + data);
            //var parsedStrs = data.split(",");
            var temperature = parseInt(data);




            sendData(temperature);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Huny,  If you reference our First IoT Sample:
https://developer.artik.cloud/documentation/tutorials/your-first-iot-device.html

The node.js sample sends the value from the temperature sensor.   As a dependency it requires a connected Arduino, Raspberry Pi, and a DHT temperature sensor located at the right pin.   If you are seeing null "before" sending the data to ARTIK Cloud, you are not getting any value from the sensor.

In particular, output and print to console the "temperature" value from the following function in case of any parsing errors:
function sendData(temperature) //...

Answer (score 0):

If you reference our First IoT Sample:
https://developer.artik.cloud/documentation/tutorials/your-first-iot-device.html

The node.js sample sends the value from the temperature sensor.   As a dependency it requires a connected Arduino, Raspberry Pi, and a DHT temperature sensor located at the right pin.   If you are seeing null "before" sending the data to ARTIK Cloud, you are not getting any value from the sensor.

In particular, output and print to console the "temperature" value from the following function in case of any parsing errors:
function sendData(temperature) //...

Email us at developer@artik.cloud if you need additional information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
var temperature = parseInt(data);
```

If you're getting empty or non numeric data (you can verify this in the previous line where you're logging the variable's content), then temperature will be NaN (not a number). Then, when you build the JSON payload for Artik Cloud, you'll end up with something like:

```
{
  "sdid": "cbd3f844967d464da3c4f4989f80f86c", 
  "data": {
    "temp":null
  }, 
  "cid":"1495817841624"
}
```

Because the JSON.stringify of:

```
{"temp":NaN}
```

would be translated to:

```
{"temp":null}
```